# Why natural numbers don't have supremum?

Tags: real-analysis, complete-spaces

As I know the definition of supremum for set $ S$ is the lowest number that is greater or equal than all the members of $S$.
This means : $\forall \: m\in R \:\:m<\sup S,\exists\: s\in S \rightarrow s> x$.
Based on this definition we have supremum for all finite subset of $\mathbb N$.
For example the $\sup S$ for $S = \{1,2,\dots, k\}$ is $k$.

Is this right?

Comment: The supremum of any finite set is it maximum

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $\mathbb R$ is also infinite, why it has $\sup$?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ has no sup. You can prove that by contradiction easily.

Comment: Then what is the definition of a complete set? as I know field F is complere if every upper bounded subset of F has $\sup$ , this condition is correct for natural numbers too but they're not complete.

Comment: The set of natural numbers is not a field !

Comment: @Amir An ordered set is complete if *any* subset - without any conditions - admits a supremum. This is the correct definition of completeness. What you attempted to describe in your comment above is *conditional completeness*: an ordered set is conditionally complete if every nonempty and upper bounded subset admits a supremum. $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard orders are both *conditionally* complete however neither is complete. Important distinctions.

Comment: @Amir There is a different (intimately related, nevertheless) sense in which $\mathbb{R}$ can be rigorously said to be complete: as an additive topological group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review [several senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) in which $\Bbb R$ is complete:

- *Each set **with an upper bound** has a least upper bound* This works in $\Bbb N$ because $\Bbb N\subseteq\Bbb R$, so if $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ then $S\subseteq\Bbb R$. Narrowly interpreted, your question boils down to overlooking the bold part; broadly interpreted viz. the comments, other respects in which $\Bbb R$ is complete are worth comparing with $\Bbb N$.
- *Each Dedekind cut is generated by a real number* Of course, they're not in general generated by *natural* numbers. (You could, I suppose, think of naturals as something similar to Dedekind cuts on themselves, but you'd gain nothing from it.)
- *Each Cauchy sequence converges to a value in $\Bbb R$* Any Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb N$ is eventually constant, converging to some natural number.
- *Intersection of interval nested, in the way the nested intervals theorem specifies, is a $1$-element set* Since naturals differ by at least $1$ (crucial also in the below discussion of IVT), you eventually can't nest proper-subset intervals further.
- *Monotone convergence* In analogy with the least-upper-bound point above, this follows because every sequence in $\Bbb N$ is also in $\Bbb R$. *Bolzano-Weierstrass* Ditto.
- *Intermediate value theorem* This fails for $\Bbb N$ because if $f(a)<0<f(b)$ then there might not be values between $a,\,b$.